# Journey Reach Miami

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

I have a question about the usage of "*journey*" and "*reach*" [here](http://articles.orlandosentinel.com/2004-10-15/entertainment/0410140381_1_che-guevara-ernesto-guevara-latin-america):

> The film also fails to adequately plumb the mystery of Che. It can't quite rip off the halo that idealists the world over have given him. Bernal's sympathetic performance doesn't do much to build on the facts that the script is anchored in -- he was a sensitive asthmatic, loyal to a fault, noble, given to quoting poetry, kind of the cliched view of leftist-idealists throughout history. This isn't Les Miz, but it might as well be.
>   Salles, who directed the Brazilian road picture Central Station, tries to demythologize Che by just piling up the details. His stubbornness in refusing to spend the $15 his girlfriend gave him to buy her an American swimsuit if ***their trip reached Miami***, his bluntness in telling a wealthy rancher that he has a tumor and the stoicism that kept them on the trip all contributed to the revolutionary he was to become, but also serve to make him human.

How does a "journey" "reach" a place?  A *journey* is an activity, and an activity does not *reach* a place.  But people on a "*journey*" could "*reach*" a place.  So, is the example poorly written?

Comment: Look over http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/reach, particularly the example "Your letter never reached me."

Comment: _is the example poorly written?_ No, the example is poorly _interpreted_ – as is the case with [so many of your questions](http://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A6362+poorly+written).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reach a place.

an area over which activity, capacity, or influence extends

second definition in Webster's online dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

This not *reach* in the sense of arriving or achieving, nor is it *reach* in the physical sense of stretching a body part toward something. But it is a basic sense, that of extension. In short, I think you are thinking too literally; this *reach* is about the travel, not the travelers.

Activities, measurements, and other abstract concepts can have a *reach* in the sense that they can have some unfixed duration, rate, or boundary, and that *reach* can be extended insofar as those parameters can be extended.

Consider these AHD-given meanings and examples for *[reach](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=reach)*:

> 5. a. To extend as far as: *The property reaches the shore.*
>      b. To project as far as: *A distant cry reached our ears.*
>      c. To travel as far as: *a long fly ball that reached the stadium's wall.*
> 6. To aggregate or amount to: *Sales reached the millions.*